# In Haskell, How user adds an item to a list

Tags: haskell

I understand how to use recursive data structures to manage a list of thingies:

```
data Thingy a = NoThingy | Thingy a a (Thingy a) deriving (Show, Read)

firstThingsFirst :: a -> a -> (Thingy a)
firstThingsFirst a b = Thingy a b NoThingy

andAnotherThing :: a -> a -> Thingy a -> Thingy a
andAnotherThing a b NoThingy = Thingy a b NoThingy
andAnotherThing a b things = Thingy a b things
```

And in ghci I can do something like:

```
let x=andAnotherThing "thing1" "thing2" NoThingy
let y=andAnotherThing "thing3" "thing4" x
```

However, I don't know how to make this work for a compiled program which takes user input.  In other words, I want to let a user fill up the structure.  Something like:

```
import System.IO
allThings=NoThingy
main = do
  putStrLn "First Thing"
  first<-getLine
  putStrLn "Second Thing"
  second<-getLine
  let allThings=Thingy first second allThings
  print allThings
  main
```

Comment: The first clause of `andAnotherThing` is redundant, since the second clause does the same thing.  For that matter `andAnotherThing` is redundant too, since it's the same as `Thing`.

Comment: Thanks all who answered.  As most of you illustrated, creating a loop and invoking it from main is precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: By the way, you could use the in-built `[(a,a)]` instead of `Thingy a`.

Answer (score 11):

Values in Haskell are immutable, so if you "add an item to a list", you get a new list. So in your code above, the

```
let allThings = Thingy first second allThings
```

doesn't do what you expect. The top-level allThings has the value `NoThingy` and that cannot change. The name `allThings` in the let-binding doesn't refer to the top-level entity, it introduces a new binding shadowing the top-level name, *and that new name is also referenced on the right hand side of the binding*.
So that line and the following are equivalent to

```
let theThings = Thingy first second theThings
print theThings
```

The let-binding creates a cyclic structure, referring to itself as one of its components. That means of course that printing it will never finish.

What you (probably) want to do requires passing the structure you want to update as a parameter

```
loop things = do
        putStrLn "First Thing"
        ...
        let newThings = Thingy first second things
        print newThings
        loop newThings
```

And of course, like Nicolas said, you probably want to convert the input strings to values of appropriate type.

Answer (score 2):

What you create is an infinitely self-referential "allThings" that gets printed.

You are binding to the name allThings twice.  The first time before main and the second time before print.

The second binding refers to allThings at then end of the right hand side.  This reference is NOT to the first binding.  This reference is to the second binding itself.

If you change the name of the second binding and of the print:

```
main = do
  putStrLn "First Thing" 
  first <- getLine
  putStrLn "Second Thing"
  second <- getLine
  let allThings2 = Thingy (read first) (read second) allThings
  print allThings2
  main
```

then you will get a single Thingy printed on each loop of main. Since you want to accumulate the answers you can define a tail-recursive "query" like this:

```
query old = do
  putStrLn "First Thing"
  first<-getLine
  putStrLn "Second Thing"
  second<-getLine
  let new=Thingy first second old
  print new
  query new

main = query NoThingy
```

The above may do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking for a way to convert from user input of type `String` to a value of type `Thingy`. Since your `Thingy` type already has an instance for `Read`, you can use the `read` function:

```
read :: Read a => String -> a
```

This makes your `main` function more like:

```
main = do
  putStrLn "First Thing" 
  first <- getLine
  putStrLn "Second Thing"
  second <- getLine
  let allThings = Thingy (read first) (read second) allThings
  print allThings
  main
```

Of course, if you enter a string that doesn't correspond to a Thingy, then you'll get an error, so you might want to use `readMay` from the [safe package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe) instead:

```
readMay :: Read a => String -> Maybe a
```

Another problem is that the type inference can't guess which type `a` is intended, so you'll also have to give it a hint, by maybe having something like:

```
let allThings = Thingy (read first :: Int) (read second :: String) allThings
```

It's probably worth noting that in this definition, `allThings` is an infinite structure, and will take forever to print: the last call to `main` will never be reached.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to use a variable to hold mutable state (like one would do in an imperative language) but you can't do so in Haskell. **All state must be explicitly passed as arguments to your functions**. As pointed in the other answers, the `allThings` inside main is actually a separate variable from the `allThings` in the global scope (it just shadows the same name)

The following example shows how to build a program that loops forever while building up a list of numbers. I think this is kind of what you want to do and it shouldn't be hard to adapt it to "Thingies"

In our case the state we have to keep for our loop is the index of the next number to be entered (1st, 2nd, etc) and the list of numbers that we have already been read. Our loop function will thus receive this state as an argument and return an IO action.

```
module Main where

-- Explicit signature so readLn and show don't complain...
loop_step :: (Int, [Int]) -> IO ()
loop_step (i,xs) = do
    putStrLn ("Enter the " ++ show i ++ "th number:")
    n <- readLn
    let newList = n : xs
    print newList
    loop_step (i+1, newList)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    loop_step (1, [])
```